# How to turn categorical data into relative counts with R

Tags: r

**Minimal example**

I have: `input<-data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,2),A=as.factor(c(1,1,2,2,1,3)),B=as.factor(c(0,1,1,1,0,0)))`

I want: `output<-data.frame(id=c(1,2), A1=c(2/3,1/3), A2=c(1/3,1/3), A3=c(0/3,1/3), B0=c(1/3,2/3), B1=c(2/3,1/3))`

**Motivation**

I have a data frame with categorical data. I would like to turn this into a dataframe with proportianal counts of each category occuring.  In the "output" dataframe I would like to have a column for each variable-category combination (A1,A2, etc.). Each row gives the relative counts for a "id". For instance, id=1 has three entries in "input" with two times category 1 under variable "A". The column "A1" should show 2/3 in that row. Divided by three, because id=1 has three entries in "input".

**What I started**

```
function(input){

#create empty dataframe
distcID<-duplicated(input$id)
output<-data.frame(id=integer(0),A1=integer(0),A2=integer(0),A3=integer(0),
                 B0=integer(0),B1=integer(0))

count<-0

for (i in input$id[distcID]){
df.cID<-input[input$customer_ID==i]
m<- NROW(df.cID)
count<-count+1
output$customer_ID[count]<-i
output$A1[count]<-1/m*NROW(df.cID$A==1)
output$A2[count]<-1/m*NROW(df.cID$A==2)
output$A3[count]<-1/m*NROW(df.cID$A==3)
output$B0[count]<-1/m*NROW(df.cID$B==0)
output$B1[count]<-1/m*NROW(df.cID$B==1)
}
return(output)

}
```

What is wrong?
- it is ugly. Given functions like apply and aggregate or a package like plyr, there should be nicer (i.e. shorter) solutions to this problem.

- R does not accept the initialization of output with empty columns.
- the column names of output are not created automatically, but by hand.

Thank you! Please tell me if my question lacks clarity. This is my first question here.

Comment: `table(dat)/sum(dat)` is the usual way. Or maybe you want to divide by `rowSums` or `colSums` but your desired output does not clarify your intent. Why is the second column not 0.5, 0.5?

Comment: @ IShouldBuyABoat: The column A2 means the proportion of times a user chose option 2 for variable A. Id=1 and id=2 chose option 2 each one times out of three choices they made. 

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression creates a table for each of the non-ID columns (here, `2:3`):

```
individuals <- lapply(2:3, function(i) {
  # Table of counts, by "id"
  x <- table(input[,c(1,i)])

  # Scale to proportions
  x <- x / rowSums(x)

  # Fix the names
  colnames(x) <- paste0(colnames(input)[i], colnames(x))

  return(x)
}
)

individuals
## [[1]]
##    A
## id         A1        A2        A3
##   1 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000
##   2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333
## 
## [[2]]
##    B
## id         B0        B1
##   1 0.3333333 0.6666667
##   2 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Now put them together with `cbind`:

```
do.call(cbind, individuals)
##          A1        A2        A3        B0        B1
## 1 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
## 2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

The `id` column is not present, but the row names can be used for this purpose.

Comment: Pretty straight forward +1

Comment: Thank you Matthew Lundberg.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer, but should help you along the way (with a bit of `resphape[2]`-ing:

```
ct <- count(input, "id")
A <- data.frame(table(input[,c(1,2)])/ct[ct$id==1,]$freq)
B <- data.frame(table(input[,c(1,3)])/ct[ct$id==2,]$freq)

print(A)
  id A      Freq
1  1 1 0.6666667
2  2 1 0.3333333
3  1 2 0.3333333
4  2 2 0.3333333
5  1 3 0.0000000
6  2 3 0.3333333

print(B)
  id B      Freq
1  1 0 0.3333333
2  2 0 0.6666667
3  1 1 0.6666667
4  2 1 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's on possible solution:

```
library(reshape2)
library(qdap)

x <- prop.table(ftable(melt(input, id="id")))
x2 <- colpaste2df(data.frame(x), 2:3, keep.orig = FALSE, sep="", name.sep = "")
x3 <- dcast(x2, id  ~ variablevalue, value.var = "Freq")
x3[, c(TRUE, colSums(x3[, -1]) != 0)]

##   id         A1         A2         A3         B0         B1
## 1  1 0.16666667 0.08333333 0.00000000 0.08333333 0.16666667
## 2  2 0.08333333 0.08333333 0.08333333 0.16666667 0.08333333
```

Comment: Thank you! When I tried library(qdap) I got an error saying that R and Java do not have matching architectures. I could probably solve this, but for now I am going to try the other solutions.

Comment: See the following for assistance: http://trinker.github.io/qdap/vignettes/qdap_vignette.html#install

Answer (score 0):

Can be seen as a pivot table (or two pivot tables):

```
>install.packages('reshape')
>library(reshape)
>ct <-count(input, "id")
>DF1<-cast(input, id ~ A, value='B')
>DF2<-cast(input, id ~ B, value="A")
>DF3<-cbind(DF1$id, DF1[names(DF1)!='id']/ct[1,]$freq, DF2[names(DF2)!='id']/ct[2,]$freq)
>names(DF3)<-c('id', paste('A', names(DF1)[-1], sep=''), paste('B', names(DF2)[-1], sep=''))
> DF3
  id        A1        A2        A3        B0        B1
1  1 0.6666667 0.3333333 0.0000000 0.3333333 0.6666667
2  2 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.6666667 0.3333333
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think you wanted. Just add row or column names to suit your tastes.

```
 tbB <- with(input, table(B, id))
 tbA <- with(input, table(A, id))
 cbind( t( tbA/rowSums(tbA)), t(tbB/rowSums(tbB)) )
          1   2 3         0         1
1 0.6666667 0.5 0 0.3333333 0.6666667
2 0.3333333 0.5 1 0.6666667 0.3333333
```